# Can 2 different task queues use the same taskoption url param value?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, task, task-queue, google-cloud-task-queue

We are using the same task option url value for the taskoptions added to the different task queues for our service.

I have the following questions:

What happens when 2 different task queues use the same url param value for the taskoptions added?
Shall we assign different task url values to taskoptions added to different task queues?
Thanks,

Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Using the same URL value for `task_options` across different queues is perfectly acceptable as long as the handler function can handle tasks from various queues based on the context (including the queue name).

When a task is added, the task queue name plays a more crucial role than the URL value within the `task_options`. The queue name is what determines which worker will handle the task. Workers are subscribed to specific queues and only process tasks from those queues.

The URL value in `task_options` typically points to the handler function that should be executed for the task. Even if the URL is the same, the context of the task (including the queue name) helps the handler differentiate between tasks from different queues.

However, using unique URLs can improve code clarity and potentially make future enhancements easier. It depends on your specific needs and code structure.